# Add custom entity in addition to NER basic model

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am using spacy to train my own NER model. In addition to entities trained by spacy basic 'en_core_web_sm' model (ORG, PERSON, DATE, etc), I want to add my own entities. I trained my model with 'en_core_web_sm' as my base model, but then the model can only detect my own custom entities only, not the basic entities. Is there any way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do this with spaCy, cf the [docs](https://spacy.io/usage/training#example-new-entity-type) and also check [Matt's blogpost](https://explosion.ai/blog/pseudo-rehearsal-catastrophic-forgetting)  around the problem of "catastrophic forgetting" (when your model "forgets" about the old types it knew before, which you obviously want to avoid).

Comment: Thanks! I tried and it worked. The problem I'm still facing is that if I trained my new entities with 'en_core_web_sm' as base model, the model missed a lot of my new entities. It gave better results for the new entities if I trained from scratch, but the model missed a lot of the original entities.